# Create shell script to ssh inside remote host and ping from that host

Tags: shell-script, ssh, ping

I want to ssh into a remote host and ping another IP from that host. However, with the following script, I am only able to ssh into that host.

```
#!/bin/sh

sshpass -p <password> ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <username>@<remote host>
/usr/sbin/ping <some IP>
```

Then, after existing from the remote host (back into my source host), the ping starts.

In other words, when my script is executed, a ssh connection is made into a remote host. Ping doesn't take place on THAT remote host. When I manually exit from the remote host, the ping starts again (from my original host).

How do I make it so that the ping starts from the remote host instead of the source host?

Comment: I'd down-vote you if I could @WinnieTigger.

Comment: use keys not sshpass.

Answer (score 6):

`ssh` takes a command to run on the remote machine as its argument, e.g.

```
ssh user@host ping ip-addr
```

This will execute `ping ip-addr` on the remote machine and then terminate the connection.

When you place the `ping` command on the next line, as in

```
ssh user@host
ping ip-addr
```

`ssh` will, by default, start an interactive shell on the remote machine.  When that shell is terminated, the control is handed back to your script, and the `ping` command is run locally.

Comment: The key point being that the remote command is supposed to be an argument or arguments to the ssh command, as opposed to being a separate command which is sent to the local shell.

Answer (score 1):

use single quotes for the commands if you want to run on a remote machine through `ssh`. will be handy to run multiple commands as well.

```
#!/bin/sh

sshpass -p <password> ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <username>@<remote host> '
/usr/sbin/ping <some IP>'
```